# Password not accepted accessing microsoftonline.com apps via OAuth Consent Screen

Tags: sharepoint, oauth, onedrive

a newbie here... Please apologize if this isn't the right place.
I'm trying to grant access some Google users to MS online apps (Teams, Sharepoint, OneDrive, ...).
Yesterday everything seemed to work well, but today I get "Your account or password is incorrect...."; but they *are* correct, of course.
I reviewed carefully the instructions, both from Microsoft and Google Console sides, I didn't find anything wrong, but of course *there must be* something wrong!
Any hint or suggestion shall be highly appreciated.
Thanks anyway for the attention.
Marco

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK, sorry, here is some background info. The Microsoft online applications (Office 365, SharePoint, Teams, OneDrive, ...) can be accessed also by external users, so called Guests. To do so the guest, identified by his/her email, must be added to the Azure Active Directory. In the AAD it is possible to use Identity Providers in order to create users, otherwise a Microsoft user is requested. The Google feature OAuth 2.0 is one of the mentioned Id Prov. The aim is to login to the MS apps with your Google credentials. The problem is that my Google id isn't accepted, although being correct.